Python multiprocessing throwing up unexplained errors
I have a python program which is separated into three files, dielectric_functions.py, routines.py and cartmoments.py, organized as follows --

dielectric_functions.py is the entry point to the program and more or less just provides structure and order to the calculation by calling in multiple functions written in routines.py.
routines.py contains most functionality, including a function that is throwing up issues with multiprocessing which will discuss now.
cartmoments.py implements class objects and certain functions on those class objects (which are parallelized).

The codes are
dielectric_functions.py:
import routines as routines

def initialize_cell() -> tuple[routines.pbcgto.cell.Cell, dict]:
    cell = routines.build_cell_from_input()                                    # Build cell object
    primgauss = routines.gen_all_1D_prim_gauss(cell)                           # Get all primitive gaussian objects
    primindices = routines.gen_prim_gauss_indices(primgauss)                   # Get all main indices for primitive gaussian objects.
    all_ao = routines.gen_all_atomic_orbitals(cell, primgauss)                 # Get all atomic orbitals
    G_vectors = routines.gen_G_vectors(cell)                                   # Get all relevant G vectors
    R_vectors = routines.construct_R_vectors(cell)
    dark_objects = {
        'primitive_gaussians': primgauss,
        'all_ao': all_ao,
        'G_vectors': G_vectors,
        'primindices': primindices[0],
        'atom_locs': primindices[1],
        'R_vectors': R_vectors
    }
    return cell, dark_objects

def dielectric_RPA(dark_objects: dict) -> None:
    routines.primgauss_1D_overlaps(dark_objects)
    return dark_objects

def main():
    cell, dark_objects = initialize_cell()
    #dark_objects = electronic_structure(cell, dark_objects)
    dark_objects = dielectric_RPA(dark_objects)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


routines.py (only relevant part):
from multiprocessing import Pool
import cartmoments
from functools import partial
import numpy as np

def time_wrapper(func):
    """
    Wrapper for printing execution time to logger.
    """
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.info('Entering function {}'.format(func.__name__))
        start = time.time()
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        logging.info('Exiting function {}. Time taken = {:.2f} s.\n'.format(func.__name__, end - start))
        return val

    return wrap

@time_wrapper
def primgauss_1D_overlaps(dark_objects: dict):
    """
    Store all 1D primitive gaussians in files. 
    NOTE: Currently returns one numpy array for all overlaps. This is not good and will not work for anisotropic systems.
    NOTE: Implement file stores with name parmt.store + '/1d_overlaps/{}_{}.npy'.format(d, q) 
    Inputs:
        dark_objects:   dict: equivalent to a class object, except not self-referential.
    """
    primindices = dark_objects['primindices']
    atom_locs = dark_objects['atom_locs']
    q, G = np.load(parmt.store + '/unique_q.npy'), dark_objects['G_vectors']
    Rv = dark_objects['R_vectors']
    makedir(parmt.store + '/primgauss_1d_integrals/')
    for d in range(3):
        qu, Gu = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(q[:,d], round_to=10), get_all_unique_nums_in_array(G[:,d], round_to=10)
        qG = (qu[:, None] + Gu[None, :]).reshape((-1))
        qG = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(qG, round_to=10)
        qG = qG[np.abs(qG) <= parmt.q_max]
        Ru = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(Rv[:,d], round_to=10)
        with Pool(10) as p:
            res = p.map(partial(cartmoments.primgauss_1D_overlaps_uR, primindices = primindices, q = qG, atom_locs = atom_locs[:,d]), Ru)
            p.close()
            p.join()
    logging.info("Generated overlaps of 1D primitive gaussians.")
    return

The issue that I am having is if I run the commands in ipython as
from dielectric_functions import *
main()

it works as expected.
However, if I attempt to run python3 dielectric_functions.py it corrupts my log, attempts to load routines.py tens of times. Note that the code actually still produces the correct results, but there is a bug there that needs to be fixed so logging can continue to exist.
cartmoments.py does not import routines.py and the entirety of function is within cartmoments.py.
I am on python 3.12.4 (main, Jun  6 2024, 18:26:44) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)] using MacOS in a virtual environment (M3 Pro, 11 cores).
I am completely lost, the fact that running the code on ipython with two separate lines and running it as python3 dielectric_functions.py are not equivalent is surprising.
----- Edit: Solved thanks to jsbueno! -----
routines.py:
import multiprocessing as mp
import cartmoments
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
...
@time_wrapper
def primgauss_1D_overlaps(dark_objects: dict):
    primindices = dark_objects['primindices']
    atom_locs = dark_objects['atom_locs']
    q, G = np.load(parmt.store + '/unique_q.npy'), dark_objects['G_vectors']
    Rv = dark_objects['R_vectors']
    makedir(parmt.store + '/primgauss_1d_integrals/')
    with mp.get_context('fork').Pool(10) as p:
        for d in range(3):
            qu, Gu = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(q[:,d], round_to=10), get_all_unique_nums_in_array(G[:,d], round_to=10)
            qG = (qu[:, None] + Gu[None, :]).reshape((-1))
            qG = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(qG, round_to=10)
            qG = qG[np.abs(qG) <= parmt.q_max]
            Ru = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(Rv[:,d], round_to=10)
            res = p.map(partial(cartmoments.primgauss_1D_overlaps_uR, primindices = primindices, q = qG, atom_locs = atom_locs[:,d]), Ru)
            res = np.array(res)
            store_primgauss_1D(d, qG, res, Ru)


While not yet sure what is happening, I can shed some light on the differences there:
While multiprocessing tries to give the impression of working magically, the fact is the Python interpreter has to be run again, loading the same modules, for each worker. The if __name__ == "__main__": guard is the only thing that prevents, in ordinary cases, the mutiprocessing-calling code to be run again in each worker.
When running python3 dialectric_functions.py from the shell, __name__ == "__main__": will be true for the first process, and should be false for when the module is loaded again for each worker. When doing import dialectric_functions from the interpreter, __name__ is not "__main__" not even for the first run.
Now, what is unusual, and although not incorrect, really looks strange, is that you create a multiprocessing Pool several times over in your code, inside a for d in range(3):. A multiprocessing Pool is an "expensive" resource in computational terms, and with the default starting method on MacOS it really implies in re-importing all loaded modules into memory, for each worker. It can be re-used without problems across several map calls, though!
It is likely that whatever is going wrong has to do with this part then, in an edge-case interaction with the first-module name.
Just move your Pool to outside the for method, so that it runs a single time, and then the processes in the Pool will be reused for each interction of d - that should fix it for you:
...
@time_wrapper
def primgauss_1D_overlaps(dark_objects: dict):
    ...
    with Pool(10) as p:
        for d in range(3):
            qu, Gu = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(q[:,d], round_to=10), get_all_unique_nums_in_array(G[:,d], round_to=10)
            qG = (qu[:, None] + Gu[None, :]).reshape((-1))
            qG = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(qG, round_to=10)
            qG = qG[np.abs(qG) <= parmt.q_max]
            Ru = get_all_unique_nums_in_array(Rv[:,d], round_to=10)
            res = p.map(partial(cartmoments.primgauss_1D_overlaps_uR, primindices=primindices, q=qG, atom_locs=atom_locs[:,d]), Ru)

No need to worry about calling "close" and "join" methods on the Pool if you are using the with statement block: it does exactly that for you.
Now, some more context, and other approaches there:
the other worker starting method for running sbpprocesses, fork used to be the default on MacOS (and is still the default on Linux) up to Python 3.8 - they've switched it because in some specific conditions, more common under MacOS, there might be problems. It is almost certain that you won't have your problem if the worker start method is set to fork instead - just do that a single time, inside your main function:
dialectric_functions.py
import multiprocessing
...

def main():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork') 
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...

Also, if calling the set_start_method function fails in this way when calling your code from the interactive shell (due to it already have been set), you will have to use an explicit context to change this setting. Then, inside the code which calls Pool, use a multiprocessing context instead:
import multiprocessing

...


@time_wrapper
def primgauss_1D_overlaps(dark_objects: dict):
    ...
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context()
    ctx.set_start_method("fork")
    with ctx.Pool(10) as P:
        for d in range(3):
            ...
```

The "fork" start method duplicates a running process in memory, as it is, and there are no `import` of other Python modules - the information from the same modules as imported in the root process is re-used. 


Thank You!
I changed the routines.py file as you recommended. One thing I forgot to note was that the code worked perfectly in Linux, which means the probelm was likely with the spawn method. I am posting the new function below for anyone who faces similar problems!
